# Configuring a ComboBox as Read-Only: Is there a way to?

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

I would Like to use a ComboBox but disable the option to type into it.

I'm trying to populate a textbox from a listbox, using a commandbutton. I can't get the button to transfer whats in the listbox unless the item in the listbox is seleceted and highlighted blue. If I use a combobox it doesn't need to be highlighted, But I don't want the option to type into the box, only select from the list.

This is my entire code that I am testing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
TextBox1 = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub


Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Creates and assigns the Array to the ListBox when the form loads.
   Dim name As Variant

   name = Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", _
      "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
   ComboBox1.List = name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the style when creating the combobox to fmStyleDropDownList this will work.

or

Put this in your code - you will have the name of the combo box below to your objects name (if you have changed it).

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList

End Sub
```